# Random falling object using timer

Tags: java, random, timer

I am trying to build a game (circus of plates), where I need to create random shapes falling and the player should catch them to increase their score. Basically, I don't have a problem with randomly creating objects, I just need them to fall.

I used the *objects pool* design pattern to create a pool containing the created object, with a method `borrowShape()` to get one object from the pool.

In the code below, I tried to use `time.schedule` to make sequentially falling objects, one after another. The problem is that I can't make them fall randomly. I think maybe the problem is with the timer as they don't fall completely - they stop at any point on the frame, and then other objects start to fall, and they also don't fall completely.

```
 public class view extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public  int x1 ;
    public  int y1 ;
    public  int x2 ;
    public  int y2 ;
    public  int Xframe ;
    public  int Yframe ;
//  Keyboard c ;
    private Image bfimage ;
    private Graphics bfg ;
    Image clown1 ;
    Image clown2 ;
    private Queue<Shapes> queue_1 = new LinkedList<Shapes>();
    private Queue<Shapes> queue_2 =  new LinkedList<Shapes>();
    private Queue<Shapes> queue_3 = new LinkedList<Shapes>();
    private Queue<Shapes> queue_4 = new LinkedList<Shapes>();
    private LinkedList<Shapes> onScreen = new LinkedList<Shapes>();
    Shapes shape_1 = new BlueMushroom();
    Shapes shape_2 = new RedMushroom();
    Shapes shape_3 = new GreenMushroom();
    Shapes shape_4 = new RedMushroom();

    ShapesPool pool;
    FirstState frstate;
    public view () throws InterruptedException{
        ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon("clown111.gif");
        clown1= i1.getImage() ;
        ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon("clown22.gif");
        clown2= i2.getImage() ;
        // create pool
        onScreen.add(new BlueMushroom());



        Xframe= 1370 ;
        Yframe = 700 ;
        setTitle("game");
        setSize(Xframe , Yframe);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        x1 = 0 ;
        y1 = Yframe - 240 ;
        x2 = 650 ;
        y2 = Yframe - 240 ;
        controller k = new controller(this , x1 , y1 , x2 , y2 , Xframe , Yframe) ;
        this.addKeyListener(k);
        Timer time = new Timer();
         pool = ShapesPool.getInstance();
         frstate = new FirstState();
        Shapes shape = new BlueMushroom();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
            shape = pool.borrowShape();
            shape.setCurrentX(randomX());
            shape.setCurrentY(10);
            shape.setState(frstate);
            queue_1.add(shape);
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++){
            shape = pool.borrowShape();
            shape.setCurrentX(randomX());
            shape.setCurrentY(10);
            shape.setState(frstate);
            queue_2.add(shape);
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++){
            shape = pool.borrowShape();
            shape.setCurrentX(randomX());
            shape.setCurrentY(10);
            shape.setState(frstate);
            queue_3.add(shape);
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 11 ; i++){
            shape = pool.borrowShape();
            shape.setCurrentX(randomX());
            shape.setCurrentY(10);
            shape.setState(frstate);
            queue_4.add(shape);
        }

        time.schedule(new RunShape(),2*1000, 2*1000);
        time.wait();

    }

int ypos1=0;
int ypos2=0;
int ypos3=0;
int ypos4=0;

    Random rand = new Random();
    public int randomX(){
        return rand.nextInt(1700);
    }

    class RunShape extends TimerTask{
        @Override
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("run");
            Shapes shape = new BlueMushroom();
            if(!queue_1.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("awl saaf ");

                shape_1 = queue_1.poll();
                addObject(shape_1);
                shape = pool.borrowShape();
                shape.setCurrentX(randomX());
                shape.setCurrentY(10);
                shape.setState(frstate);
                queue_1.add(shape);
            }
            if(!queue_2.isEmpty()){

                shape_2 = queue_2.poll();
                addObject(shape_2);
                shape = pool.borrowShape();
                shape.setCurrentX(randomX());
                shape.setCurrentY(10);
                shape.setState(frstate);
                queue_2.add(shape);
            }
            if(!queue_3.isEmpty()){

                shape_3 = queue_3.poll();
                addObject(shape_3);
                shape = pool.borrowShape();
                shape.setCurrentX(randomX());
                shape.setCurrentY(10);
                shape.setState(frstate);
                queue_3.add(shape);
            }
            if(!queue_4.isEmpty()){

                shape_4 = queue_4.poll();
                addObject(shape_4);
                shape = pool.borrowShape();
                shape.setCurrentX(randomX());
                shape.setCurrentY(10);
                shape.setState(frstate);
                queue_4.add(shape);
            }
            Timer time = new Timer();
            time.schedule(new TimerTask(){
                public void run(){
                    while(ypos1 <= 1600){
                        ypos1++;
                        shape_1.setCurrentY(ypos1);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        ypos2++;
                        shape_2.setCurrentY(ypos2);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        ypos3++;
                        shape_3.setCurrentY(ypos3);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        ypos4++;
                        shape_4.setCurrentY(ypos4);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        repaint();
                    }
                    if(ypos1 == 1600 ){ ypos1 = 0;
                    shape_1.setCurrentY(ypos1);
                    }
                    if(ypos2 == 1600 ){ ypos2 = 0;
                    shape_2.setCurrentY(ypos2);
                    }
                    if(ypos3 == 1600 ){ ypos3 = 0;
                    shape_3.setCurrentY(ypos3);
                    }
                    if(ypos4 == 1600 ){ ypos4 = 0;
                    shape_4.setCurrentY(ypos4);
                    }

            }
            },1*1000 ,1*1000);
            try {
                time.wait(1*1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }
    }


    public void addObject(Shapes shape){
        onScreen.add(shape);
        repaint();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        bfimage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight()) ;
        bfg = bfimage.getGraphics() ;
        paintcomponent(bfg) ;
        g.drawImage(bfimage, 0, 0, this) ;

    }

    public void paintcomponent(Graphics g){ 
        g.drawImage(clown1, x1, y1, this) ;
        g.drawImage(clown2, x2, y2, this) ;
        for(Shapes shape : onScreen){
                g.drawImage(shape.getMushroom(), shape.getCurrentX(), shape.getCurrentY(), this);   
        }

        repaint() ;
    }   

}
```

Comment: so what's your question and problem?

Comment: I can't make them fall randomly, I think may be the problem with the timer as the don't complete the falling and stop at any point on the frame, and then other objects start to fall, and also don't complete falling.

Comment: great, so bring the comment into the question for more clarifying